# POST file - not from client machine, from web/ftp server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, post

I'm using .Net.

Is it possible for a web form to upload an image from a web or FTP server? The files I need to submit are on the web. If this is possible, code snippet is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to interact with other web servers in .Net server-side code.

For example:

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
    client.UploadFile("ftp://server/path", @"C:\path\to\file");
```

If the file is on a different website, you can write the following:

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
     client.UploadData("ftp://server/path", client.DownloadData("http://server/path"));
```

You can read and write FTP, HTTP, and HTTPS urls interchangeably.

Comment: Can you explain this further? I need to POST (web form) the file.

Comment: You can POST the file by replacing `ftp://server/path` with the full URL that you want to POST to.

Comment: And what if I need to pass other parameters, too? For example, in an email application, one would need to pass a "to" address, a "subject", a "body", and a file attachment.